# SonarLint for Eclipse supports the C/C++ plugin?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, sonarqube

With version 2.0 of the [SonarLint plugin for Eclipse](http://www.sonarlint.org/eclipse/) it's now possible to sync rules from a SonarQube 5.2+ server instance.

By default there is no C language support in SonarLint but if the server instance has installed the [C plugin](http://www.sonarsource.com/products/plugins/languages/cpp/), **does this mean that SonarLint can analyze C projects?**

> With version 2.0 you can now establish a connection to a SonarQube server (5.2+) and bind your Eclipse project to a SonarQube project.
>
> ...
>
> SonarLint is an Eclipse plugin that provides on-the-fly feedback to
>   developers on new bugs and quality issues injected into Java,
>   JavaScript and PHP code.
>
> Source: http://www.sonarlint.org/eclipse/ (2016-04-19)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SonarLint for Eclipse currently only supports Java, JavaScript and PHP. Support for other languages - including those backed by commercial plugins like C/C++, is in our backlog but I can't give an ETA for this yet.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a backlog ID that you could share so that we may vote for it?

Comment: In our internal product backlog, yes. But I can't give the link here.

Comment: @Fabrice_-_SonarSource_Team Version 2.1.0 has support for "some commerical plugins". Can you explain more what this means? Seen on: http://www.sonarlint.org/eclipse/index.html

Comment: It means that if you have purchased a license of a commercial plugin (like COBOL or PL/SQL for instance), then SonarLint will now be able to use those plugins when it is connected to the SonarQube instance on which you installed those commercial plugins.

Comment: Yes, I realize that thank you. Is C/C++ among those languages that are now supported? Is there such a list somewhere?

Comment: Not yet for C/C++. All other commercial plugins are supported.